# Functions fires regardless of the eventListeners

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I am trying to change the background of the section when the user is viewing it, however, when I added the eventlistners they didn't work properly. they fire as if there were no eventlistners. your assistance is much appreciated.

please find my JS code below

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");

// this function changes the background of the section to show it is the active one
const activeSection = section => {
  section.style.backgroundColor = "#6BCAE2";
};

// this function return the section to its normal status when the user is not viewing it anymore
const inactiveSection = section => {
  section.style.backgroundColor = "";
};

// to loop throught the nodelist and add eventlistneres for the functions above
for (let section of sections) {
  section.addEventListener("mouseover", activeSection(section));
  section.addEventListener("mouseout", inactiveSection(section));
}
```

Comment: You will want your functions to return a function expression. Eg.  `return () => section.style....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an *anonymous function* to pass in your parameter:

```js
for (let section of sections) {
  section.addEventListener("mouseover", () => { activeSection(section); });
  section.addEventListener("mouseout", () => { inactiveSection(section); });
}
```

Comment: No problem! You can mark this answer as accepted if it helped you. :)